# PDO Transaction with Prepared Statements not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions, prepared-statement

I have a PDO Transaction in which I'm trying to use prepared statements to run two queries on my database. They're both insert statements, they insert data from Facebook into two separate tables (named "player" and "bank").

The Facebook data is sent to this php script by an AJAX post. I've made sure my database is InnoDB, so it is compatible with PDO Transactions, and the Facebook data is reaching the php script (because I tried a basic/unsecure Insert statement with this AJAX post and it worked perfectly), but I can't seem to get the Transaction to work with prepared statements. I think I'm integrating the two incorrectly.

This is my current code:

```
<?php
$servername = "myserver";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydatabase";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $conn->beginTransaction();

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO player (fb_id, f_name, l_name, email, gender) 
    VALUES (:fb_id, :firstname, :lastname, :email, :gender)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':fb_id', $userid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $userfirst_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $userlast_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $useremail);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $usergender);

    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $userfirst_name = $_POST['userfirst_name'];
    $userlast_name = $_POST['userlast_name'];
    $useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
    $usergender = $_POST['usergender'];
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO bank (fb_id, cb, gb, invite) 
    VALUES (:fb_id, :cb, :gb, :invite)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':fb_id', $userid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cb', $cb);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gb', $gb);
    $stmt->bindParam(':invite', $invite);

    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $cb = "100";
    $gb = "0";
    $invite = "0";
    $stmt->execute();

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
?>
```

I've tried using `alert(response);` to see what the output of this PHP is, but it's giving me a blank result.

If anyone could give me any advice on this that would be awesome! 
Also, is this a pretty secure method of running queries on my database? Is it secure from injection attacks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is error reporting turned on? Make sure it's `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? [Quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: You need to commit your transaction. Use [$conn->commit()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.commit.php) in the end of your script (after execute) to apply changes to your db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each transaction should begin with

```
beginTransaction()
```

and end with

```
commit()
```

You can commit the transaction just after you execute the last query:

```
$stmt->execute();
$conn->commit();
```